# CSS3 radial gradient appears as line

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I've been trying to create a radial background, except for some reason all I can get is a line. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3QSFj/1/

CSS:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, circle, 0, circle, 70, color-stop(0%, #718aa7), color-stop(70%, #203044));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #718aa7 0%, #203044 70%);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #718aa7 0%, #203044 70%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, #718aa7 0%, #203044 70%);
background: radial-gradient(circle, #718aa7 0%, #203044 70%);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your `body` `height` to `100%`, your `body` element is empty, and thus it doesn't have any `height`, the `background` is simply `repeated` there.. <s>[Bad Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3QSFj/4/)</s>

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QSFj/2/)

Also, you `background` will be repeated, so you will need `background-attachment: fixed;` as well as `background-repeat: no-repeat`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QSFj/3/)